# Is there a safe way to safely delete a Model field in Django?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models

I'm making a blog application in Django, and I want to modify a field of the Post class:
I want to change the `meta_description` field to just `description`.

From:

```py
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True) 
    meta_description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    body = models.TextField()
    
    def __str__(self):
        """
        Show the title and the author in the admin Page
        """
        return self.title + " by " + str(self.author)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("blog:article_page", kwargs={"pk": self.pk})
    ⏎
```

To:

```py
    class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True) 
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    body = models.TextField()
    
    def __str__(self):
        """
        Show the title and the author in the admin Page
        """
        return self.title + " by " + str(self.author)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("blog:article_page", kwargs={"pk": self.pk})
```

When I do that in the model: I have an error Making the migration:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/daniel/MEGA/my-git/github/Developer-road-website/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/daniel/MEGA/my-git/github/Developer-road-website/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/daniel/MEGA/my-git/github/Developer-road-website/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/daniel/MEGA/my-git/github/Developer-road-website/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 368, in execute
    self.check()
  File "/home/daniel/MEGA/my-git/github/Developer-road-website/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 392, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "/home/daniel/MEGA/my-git/github/Developer-road-website/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 70, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "/home/daniel/MEGA/my-git/github/Developer-road-website/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/home/daniel/MEGA/my-git/github/Developer-road-website/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "/home/daniel/MEGA/my-git/github/Developer-road-website/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 408, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/home/daniel/MEGA/my-git/github/Developer-road-website/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/daniel/MEGA/my-git/github/Developer-road-website/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 589, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/home/daniel/MEGA/my-git/github/Developer-road-website/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/daniel/MEGA/my-git/github/Developer-road-website/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 582, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/daniel/MEGA/my-git/github/Developer-road-website/DeveloperRode/DeveloperRode/urls.py", line 26, in <module>
    path("blog/", include('blog.urls')),
  File "/home/daniel/MEGA/my-git/github/Developer-road-website/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/daniel/MEGA/my-git/github/Developer-road-website/DeveloperRode/blog/urls.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .views import BlogView, ArticleDetail, PostCreateView, EditPost, PostDeleteView
  File "/home/daniel/MEGA/my-git/github/Developer-road-website/DeveloperRode/blog/views.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .forms import PostForm, EditForm
  File "/home/daniel/MEGA/my-git/github/Developer-road-website/DeveloperRode/blog/forms.py", line 4, in <module>
    class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
  File "/home/daniel/MEGA/my-git/github/Developer-road-website/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 268, in __new__
    raise FieldError(message)
```

What Can I do?

Comment: These are `ModelForm`s that still use the old `meta_description`. You will need to search for occurrences in forms, (class-based) views and serializer (if you define these) for uses of `meta_description` and change these as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this happens is because besides models, you likely have forms, views, serializers, etc. that still use `meta_description`. If you thus have a `PostForm` like:

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['meta_description']
        # change to description ↑
```

then you should alter this to `description` as well. You thus should perform a search with `meta_description` through your project and alter the occurrences of `meta_description`, but *be careful*: not all the `meta_description`s per see refer to the field of the `Post` model, if it is about another model, you of course should not modify this.

Comment: I just realized it, Thanks!  for the quick reply!

Answer (score 1):

I solved the Problem, It seem to be a Form problem, where I was calling the Old field meta_description.

I correct it in `forms.py` file and make the `makemigrations` command, after that it showed a prompt:

```
Did you rename post.meta_description to post.description (a TextField)? [y/N] y
```

And now there the problem is solved.